# A combinatorial question for divergent sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, matrices, convergence-divergence

Suppose $C=\{ a_{i,j} \}_{i,j \in \Bbb{Z}}$ is a symmetric complex bisequence (which means $a_{i,j}=a_{j,i}$) such that $\sum_{i \le j} \lvert a_{i,j} \rvert$ diverges. Call $P \subseteq \Bbb{Z}^2$ square-symmetric if $P=F \times F$ for some finite set $F \subseteq \Bbb{Z}$. Denote by $S$ the collection of $\sum_{(i,j) \in P} a_{i,j}$ for all square-symmetric $P$'s. Must $S$ be unbounded? The square-symmetric restriction really annoyed me and I don't know where to start. Even a result about the case $a_{i,j}=\pm 1$ is of great help to me!

**PS**: The problem can be stated in a matrix-manner: Suppose the entry-wise $l^1$-norm of a countably-infinite symmetric complex matrix is unbounded, must the entry-sums of its finite principal minors be also unbounded?

Comment: Counterexample: $a_{i,j}=1/\max(i^2,j^2)$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest This can not be counterexample since your numbers are positive. In this (and similar) case, the square-symmetric sums (indexed by $n$) correspond to $\{ (i,j)|1 \le i,j \le n \}$ are unbounded.

Comment: $\{(i,j)\mid 1\le i\le n \text{ and }1\le j\le n\}$ is not a finite union of $\{(k,k)\}$ and $\{(i,j),(j,i),(i,i),(j,j)\}$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest $$\{(i,j)\mid 1\le i\le n \text{ and }1\le j\le n\}= \bigcup_{1 \le i<j \le n} \{(i,j),(j,i),(i,i),(j,j)\}$$ Am I missing something? By union, I mean set-theoretic union.

Comment: @MikeEarnest And I also change my question now. I found it not what I want to ask.

Comment: Never mind, I was confused, and thinking of "disjoint union" instead of union. Interesting question...

Comment: Is $P\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^2$ a "square-symmetric set" if and only if $P=F \times F$ for some finite set $F \subset \mathbb{Z}$?